# Problem with next() and previous() methods in ListIterator in java

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main_songs {
public static Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
public static PlayList play=new PlayList();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     boolean quit=false;
     while(!quit) {
     System.out.println("Enter your choice");
     System.out.println("0.quit\n"+
                        "1.Add song in playlist\n"+
                        "2.remove song from playlist\n"+
                        "3.forward song\n"+
                        "4.backward song\n"+
                        "5.replay current song\n"+
                        "6.list all songs\n"+
                        "7.create new album\n"+
                        "8.Add songs to album");
     int choice=scanner.nextInt();
     scanner.nextLine();
     switch(choice) {
     case 0:
         quit=true;
         break;
     case 1:
         System.out.println("Enter the album name");
         String album_name=scanner.nextLine();
         Album album=play.findAlbum(album_name);
        if(album!=null) {
         System.out.println("Enter the song tilte");
         String title=scanner.nextLine();
         Song song=album.findSong(title);
         if(song!=null) {
         play.addSongs(album_name, song);
         System.out.println("Song added in the playlist");}
         else {
             System.out.println("Song not found in the album");}}
         else
             System.out.println("album not found");
         break;
     case 2:
         System.out.println("Enter the song title");
         String title=scanner.nextLine();
         play.removeSong(title);
         break;
     case 3:
        play.skipForward();
         break;
     case 4:
         play.skipBackward();
         break;
     case 5:
         play.Replay();
         break;
     case 6:
         play.listSongs();
         break;
     case 7:
         System.out.println("Enter the album name");
         String album_title=scanner.nextLine();
         play.createNewAlbum(album_title);
         break;
     case 8:
         System.out.println("Enter the album name");
         String albumName=scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter the song name");
         String song_name=scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter the song duration");
         double duration=scanner.nextDouble();
         play.addSongtoAlbum(albumName, song_name, duration);
         break;

     }
     }

}

package linkedList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class PlayList {

private LinkedList<Song> playlist=new LinkedList<Song>();
private ArrayList<Album> album_list;
private ListIterator<Song> list=playlist.listIterator();

public PlayList() {
    this.album_list=new ArrayList<Album>();

}
public LinkedList<Song> getPlaylist(){
    return this.playlist;
}
public ArrayList<Album> getAlbum_list(){
    return this.album_list;
}

public void addSongs(String album_name,Song song) {

        playlist.add(song);

}
public void listSongs() {
    for(int i=0;i<playlist.size();i++) {
        Song song=playlist.get(i);
        System.out.println("Songs are "+song.getTitle() +" and duration is "+song.getDuration());}
}

public void createNewAlbum(String album_name) {
    Album album=findAlbum(album_name);
    if(album==null) {
        album_list.add(new Album(album_name));
        System.out.println("New album created succesfully");
    }else
        System.out.println("This album is already exist");
}
public Album findAlbum(String title) {
    for(int i=0;i<album_list.size();i++) {
        Album album=album_list.get(i);
        if(album.getAlbum_name().equals(title)) {
            return album;
        }
    }return null;}
public void skipForward() {
    list = playlist.listIterator();
    if (list.hasNext()) {
        list.next();
        if (list.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Playing next song " + list.next().getTitle());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Currently playing last song");
        }
    }
}

public void skipBackward() {
    list = playlist.listIterator();
    if (list.hasPrevious()) {
        list.previous();
        if (list.hasPrevious()) {
            System.out.println("Playing previous song " + list.previous().getTitle());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Currently playing last song");
        }
    }
}

public void Replay() {

    boolean goingForward=true;
    if(goingForward) {
        if(list.hasPrevious()) {
            System.out.println("Now replaying "+list.previous().getTitle());

        goingForward=false;
       }else
           System.out.println("Now playlist at the start");}
    else
     if(list.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Now replaying "+list.next().getTitle());
        goingForward=true;
    }else
        System.out.println("Playlist come to end");

}
public void removeSong(String title) {

    if(playlist.size()>0) {
        list.remove();
        System.out.println("Deleted current song");
    if(list.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Now you are playing "+list.next().getTitle());
    }
    if(list.hasPrevious()) {
        System.out.println("Now you are playing "+list.previous().getTitle());
    }
}
}
public void addSongtoAlbum(String album_name,String title,double duration) {
    Album album=findAlbum(album_name);
    if(album!=null) {
        if(album.getAlbum_name().equals(album_name)) {
            album.addSongs(title, duration);
        }else
            System.out.println("Album not exist");
    }else
        System.out.println("This album not exist");
}

}


package linkedList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Album {
private String album_name;
private ArrayList<Song> song_list=new ArrayList<Song>();
public Album(String album_name) {
    this.album_name=album_name;

}
public String getAlbum_name() {
    return album_name;
}
public ArrayList<Song> getSongs(){
    return this.song_list;
}
public boolean addSongs(String title,double duration) {
    Song song=findSong(title);
    if(song==null) {
        song_list.add(new Song(title,duration));
        System.out.println("song added successfully");
        return true;
    }else {
        System.out.println("This song already exist in the list");
        return false;
    }

}
public Song findSong(String title) {
    for(int i=0;i<song_list.size();i++) {
        Song song=song_list.get(i);
        if(song.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            return song;
        }
    }return null;
}

}

package linkedList;

public class Song {
private String title;
private double duration;
public Song(String title,double duration) {
    this.title=title;
    this.duration=duration;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public double getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
}
```

Hi,
I posted a part of the code. The program is based on the Linked list with list iterator concept. Create one album. From that album need to select the songs and put in a playlist. Here I have a problem with move forward and move backward functions. Forward function only forwards one time. Then it repeating the same song. The backward function is not working. It just prints No song in previous. Could anyone help me and suggest me some ideas. Thank you.

In my code, it is creating the album and adding the songs and then it is adding the songs from the album to playlist and then finally it is printing all songs from the playlist. After that in forward() method, it is just forward only one song. Then it is repeating the same song.In backward() method it just check the hasPrevious().After it fails to proceed further. Replay method also the same, it is saying the start of the list.Remove() method is saying Exception illegalStateException.

Could anyone check my code and give me feedback please.

Comment: Both methods get a new iterator when they are called, this means you are always at the start of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Before every `next` call `hasNext`. The same for `previous`.

```
        Song sing = list.next();
        System.out.println("Playing next song "+sing.getTitle());
```

should be

```
        Song sing = list.next();
        System.out.println("Playing next song "+sing.getTitle());
```

or (because of that "skip")

```
        list.next();
        if (list.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Playing next song "+list.next().getTitle());
        }
```

Comment: You mean `List curr = list.next(); ... curr.getTitle() ...` (as list.getTitle() won't compile).

Comment: @DodgyCodeException very true, though `WhateverItem curr = list.next()` probably not list. Corrected

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.Still it has same problem. Now i posted full program.Please visit and give me your feedback.